# add a row to Gridview from an array string without defining columns c#

Tags: c#

RE ABOVE - SOLVED WITH THE FOLLOWING CODE EXTRACT:

```
string columnNameQuery = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM [Flushing Rig 20251].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + DBComms.localDB.dbTableName + "'";
            //get the headers of the columns in SQL and copy them to the gridview on the form
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(tempCon))
            {
                
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(columnNameQuery, connection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adp.Fill(dt);
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    dgLocalDBRes.Columns[i].HeaderText = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                }
            }
            //Execute the Search query
            //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBComms.localDB.dbConString))
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(tempCon))
            {                
                try
                {
                    // Read all data from the database
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (!reader.IsDBNull(i))
                                    rowToAdd[i] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                            }
                            dgLocalDBRes.Rows.Add(rowToAdd);
                            resFound++;
                       
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (!errLogged)
                                catProcs.LogEvent("frmLocalDB-btnSearch. Error populating results from reader. 1 or more results not displayed. Error: " + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    reader.Close();
```

> I'm trying to add a new row to gridview from an SQL database which has over 250 columns (which means hard code defining the columns might be difficult. Any thoughts on possibly doing this inside a loop?

Here is my current attempt using Windows forms applications,

```
        columnString = "SELECT '[" + DBComms.localDB.dbTableName + "]', COUNT (*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(tempCon))
        {                               
            SqlCommand columnCounter = new SqlCommand(columnString, connection);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader columnReader = columnCounter.ExecuteReader();
                while (columnReader.Read())
                {
                    columnCount = int.Parse(columnReader[1].ToString()); //set the number of columns for loop later
                }
                columnReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving Number of Columns from Database");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        columnCount = columnCount - 5;
        string[] rowToAdd = new string[columnCount];

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(tempCon))
            {                
                try
                {
                    // Read all data from the database
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (!reader.IsDBNull(i))
                                    rowToAdd[i] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                            }
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowToAdd);
                            resFound++;
```

Comment: it seems you have posted incomplete code

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this.

```
 select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='your table name'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response

Comment: The query is fine (table name being called from elsewhere in code)

Comment: when i add dgLocalDBRes.ColumnCount = columnCount; to the code i am able to populate the gridview with data. but the Column names are left blank,

Comment: is there a way to populate the column headers from sql as well as the data? thanks!

Comment: Keep this columns name in one list (or) array and take sql data values another query with list or array, and do mapping both.